# json_decode($request->array) returns empty value on one of the object properties (image file) - array(0) { } {"photo":null}

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js, object

**Dynamic Form**

Adding and removing boxes works fine and data is fed well upon entering text on form. Even the photo is being captured very well

```
<form>
    <div class="box" v-for="(data,i) in datas" :key="i">
        <input type="text" v-model="data[i]['key1']>
        <input type="text" v-model="data[i]['key2']>
        <input type="file" @change="selectImage($event,i)">

        // I have not included add/delete methods to reduce codes
        <button @click.prevent="method_to_add_box">Add</button>
        <button @click.prevent="method_to_delete_box">Del</button>

        <button @click.prevent="submitData">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Vuejs scripts**

```
datas: [
    {key1:'value1',key2:'value2',photoToUpload:null}
],
methods: {
    submitData() {
        let theData = new FormData();
        theData.append('datas',JSON.stringify(this.datas));
        let config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
            }
        };
        axios.post('/url', theData, config)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },
    selectImage(event, i) {
        let theImage = event.target.files[0];
        this.datas[i].photoToUpload = theImage;
    }
}
```

**I receive the data in Laravel backend**

```
$datas = json_decode($request->datas);

if(is_array($datas)) {
    foreach($datas as $data) {
        $object = new Object();

        $object->field1 = $data->key1;
        $object->field2 = $data->key2;

        // problem starts here - photo seen as an empty object so can't store()
        $path = $data->photoToUpload->store('/path');
        $path = explode('/',$path); $filename = $path[2]

        $object->photo = $filename;

        if($object->save()) {
            return new ObjectResource($object);
        }
    }
}
```

**Troubleshooting & Results**

Tried to return response immediately after json_decode($request->datas) and here are the results;

```
$datas = json_decode($request->datas);
return \response([$datas[0]->photoToUpload]);
```

Developer Tools Network Tab response returns

```
[{ }], status is OK
```

have also tried returning extension of the photo

```
return \response([$datas[0]->photoToUpload->extension()]);
```

Developer Tools Network Tab preview returns message below

> **"Call to undefined method stdClass::extension()", Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error**

However, if I don't put the fileToUpload inside an array in Vuejs data I can append to formdata, receive in Laravel backend and upload without troubles.

What am I doing wrong here? Please assist

Comment: Less explanation, more code please. `console.log(array)`. `var_dump($request->array)`.

Comment: Sorry, Correction. If i assign the selected image to any other property out of the array and append to FormData it works without trouble. If assigned in any property inside an array, that particular image/file key returns empty object. I think this is clear now

Comment: Thanks deceze, var_dump() returns object(stdClass)#265 (0) { } {"dayphoto":null}